# About iOS Game - upgrade

Tags: ios

The game is simple:
Press Button - gain money, with money - (1)build shops, (2)upgrade.

and that 2 points are problem to me.

first. build shops
If I build a shop, the shop gains money itself per sec.
That mean the process have to run every seconds. 
Is there some codes can do this?

second. upgrade
I already made one code about upgrade.

```
- (IBAction)upgrade:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sum >= 100000){
        i = 300;
        sum = sum - 100000;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"업그레이드 성공!" message:@"당신의 버거가 업그레이드 되었습니다! 축하합니다" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"예, 감사합니다!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"업그레이드 할 수 없습니다" message:@"총 금액이 부족합니다" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"예, 더 모을께요" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
    }
}
```

However, the problem is I planed 93 upgrades for this..
Do I have to write down like this code for 93?
and if I upgrade at once, it shouldn't upgrade again!.

For Example, You already upgraded once with your money '100000'
and you should upgrade next (not 100000) but for now that code can upgrade..
So, Are there some codes that can lock the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first second question: Just use a timer.  There's plenty of guides online on how to use an NSTimer so I'm not going to include a sample here, that's an exercise for the reader :)

For the second question, sounds like you need a database (of sorts)!

Something simple like one in JSON would work (although it'll be very easy to hack ;) ).

For example:

```
{ "upgrades":[
    {"id":1, "cost":1000, "perSec":1}, 
    {"id":2, "cost":10000, "perSec":2}
  ]
}
```

Etc.

Then you need a flag to know that you have previously purchased it (use NSUserDefaults, store it in core data or sqlite, it doesn't matter where, as long as you store it somewhere).  Then you can just find the next unpurchased upgrade and sell it.

If your upgrades scale algorithmicly you don't even need a database, you just need to store the previous upgrade and the upgrade number (is it the first upgrade? second? etc) and perform the algorithm to get the next one.